The [autogen] tag is misused
According to the tag wiki, autogen refers to GNU AutoGen.
Recently, the tag is mostly used for Microsoft AutoGen, or derived language bindings, which is related to AI and to my understanding has nothing to do with GNU AutoGen.
What should be done about this?

Create a separate tag for GNU AutoGen?
Create a separate tag for Microsoft AutoGen?
Ignore


Don't accept an answer until the situation is solved. It'll help others notice.

GNU AutoGen is dead as a dodo, last release in 2015. I would not expect newer questions...

@usr1234567 you might be surprised but people some times use old technology. In some cases it's technology that was used in a project that was current at the time but the project was never updated for any reason. I have a project at work that uses a framework where the last release was in 2014, for example.

I was scrolling down the list of 88 questions, and there's one point where all the questions start being used for AI related questions, and that seems relatively recent. Interestingly, there's about 42 AI autogen related questions, so around half of them is AI related.
Given that there's just 88 of them, I'd suggest the following steps:

Manually retag the new AI related ones to ms-autogen. Also remember to edit the bad questions into shape and not just change the tag. If the questions are not on-topic for the site, remember to vote to close them.

Get a mod to rename the old tag to gnu-autogen. This is to ensure that the tag autogen wouldn't be misused again. Additionally, if a mod does this, it will not create any revisions, and hence won't kick those questions to the front page.

Update both the tag wikis to explicitly mention the other tag. The tag excerpt should be updated to say when not to use this tag.



A bit more work for non-moderators, but "(1) create tag [tag:ms-autogen] and create its wiki (mentioning tag [tag:gnu-autogen]) and retag the relevant questions; (2) create tag [tag:gnu-autogen] and create its wiki from the existing [tag:autogen] wiki (and mention the tag [tag:ms-autogen]) and retag the relevant questions; (3) let the system drop the old [tag:autogen] tag because it is no longer in use".  That doesn't need moderator assistance if the person doing the work has sufficient privileges (>20k — the threshold might be lower than that).

But that'd create revisions, and bump questions to the main page. A mod can do it in literal seconds.

And, importantly, users should not add the tag [artificial-intelligence] to ms autogen questions; if all ms autogen questions are inherently about "AI", then adding such a generic tag is not much use.

We should be able to do it in seconds, but the tag merge feature appears to be broken at the moment. I'm getting a 500 error from the server when I try.

@CodyGray yeah, there is a bug report for that on the mod-teams.

Yes, I've been pointed at the nearly month-old bug report (mod-only link, for reference). The key is not just having the bug reported, but actually fixing it.

Update: Tag merges have been fixed, so this is now actually completed.
